# I am having problem's with adding a filter in Kohana 3.1

Tags: validation, hash, webforms, kohana-3

I am having some problems adding a callback filter in Kohana 3.1.

Here is my validator:

```
Validation::factory($fields)
                    ->rules('username', $this->_rules['username'])
                    ->rule('username', 'username_available', array($this, ':field'))
                    ->rules('email', $this->_rules['email'])
                    ->rule('email', 'email_available', array($this, ':field'))
                    ->rules('password', $this->_rules['password'])
                    ->rules('password_confirm', $this->_rules['password_confirm'])
                    ->filter('password', $this->_filters['password']);
```

Here is the array for the filter:

```
protected $_filters = array(
            'password' => array(
                    'Auth::instance' => 'hash'
            )
    );
```

It used to look like this:

```
 public function filters()
 {
   return array(
           'password' => array(
                   array(array(Auth::instance(), 'hash'))
           )
   );
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Validation::filter()

Comment: On this line: ->filter('password', $this->_filters['password']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation in Kohana 3.1+ doesn't support filters, it's ORM-only feature.

Comment: ORM in Ko3.1 also has no filters. Only rules.

Comment: @biakaveron: that's why I'm implying